# execution perl script from batch file

Tags: shell

I have this script shell and i want to execute it in windows:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Create the structure of folders that will contain the result files
export perl_git_dir=path1
export OUTPUT_DIR=path2
mkdir $OUTPUT_DIR/output_perl

for FILE in `ls *.sh`
 do
    echo  "file is:"$FILE
    if [ -f "$FILE" ];then
        name=${FILE%.*}
        mkdir -p $OUTPUT_DIR/output_perl/"$name"
    fi;     
done

for entry in `ls *.sh`
 do
    if [ -f "$entry" ];then
        echo "enty is "$entry 
        echo "$entry" >> stdout.txt
        echo "$entry" >> stderr.txt
        ./$entry >> stdout.txt 2>> stderr.txt
    fi;     
done
```

the result that I have is:
the creation of the direcory then this repetitive error in "stderr.txt" file

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘path1/output_perl’: File exists
```

Comment: You should probably add the whole output of your script, not just the error. Why do you use `for FILE in \`ls *.sh\`; do` instead of file globbing, i.e. `for FILE in *.sh; do`?

Comment: This does not appear to be a DOS/Windows [tag:batch-file]...

Comment: Updated tags, as I can't see any Perl code.

Comment: It is also not clear why the script generates `${OUTPUT_DIR}/output_perl/${basename}`. It seems unused, e.g. the scripts are not executed in its directory.

Answer (score 1):

Code seems to do what it is supposed to do. In my example I replaced `.sh` with `.pl` as I don't have any script files lying around. NOTE: the execution errors are expected.

I can only assume that the question is too incomplete to be answered...

```shell
#!/bin/sh
_output_dir=path2

for f in *.pl; do
    basename=${f%.*}
    mkdir -p ${_output_dir}/output_perl/${basename}
    echo ${f} >>stdout.txt
    echo ${f} >>stderr.txt
    ./${f} >>stdout.txt 2>>stderr.txt
done

exit 0
```

Test run:

```
$ sh dummy.sh 

$ cat stdout.txt 
dummy2.pl
dummy.pl
standard.pl
$ cat stderr.txt 
dummy2.pl
dummy.sh: line 9: ./dummy2.pl: Permission denied
dummy.pl
dummy.sh: line 9: ./dummy.pl: Permission denied
standard.pl
dummy.sh: line 9: ./standard.pl: Permission denied

$ ls path2/output_perl/
dummy  dummy2  standard
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, i just put the script in the adequate path and it works